# Manipulate body and html background from a component in a nuxt.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I load data via http get from an api inside a component. This data includes dynamic color hex code.

I need to modify the html, body background-color property to this hex code.

I have searched to modify the header css, but i could not find a solution.

```
return app.$axios.post('http://localhost/ea/api/collections/get/Projekte',
{filter: { Slug: 'getdata'}})

.then(res => {return {siteData: res.data.entries[0]}})
```

> siteData ... includes hex eg. siteData.background: '#ffff'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use pure Javascript code that manipulate your DOM:

```js
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor=siteData.background
//document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor='#ff5'
```

you could also create a `computed` property to do that